# BDD & Test Coverage

Tags: unit-testing, bdd

I have started writing my first BDD tests for iOS, using Quick and Nimble, and I have a question about test coverage.

I realize that in traditional unit tests, developers aim to have 100% test coverage. However, I haven't read that for BDD. If I am understanding BDD correctly, when I am testing the behavior of my code, then the little details of the implementations don't matter; what matters is that I get the expected outcome from my code, correct?

I started trying to get 100% code coverage, but it seems like I am starting to write brittle tests because instead of focusing on the outcome of my code, I am trying to cover all of the paths that my code can take.

1. Am I understanding BDD correctly?
2. Does aiming for 100% code coverage defeat the purpose of BDD?

Comment: the difference of BDD and TDD is not about test coverage, it is about focusing on the behavior in of the software rather than testing implementation detail(Test the API not the implementation as some call it) ,BDD and TDD both will lead to 100% code coverage because one of the main ideas is writing the test first before any implementation code.

Comment: You can have 100% test coverage with both, but BDD will ensure you to have developped the right thing.

Comment: "I realize that in traditional unit tests, developers aim to have 100% test coverage". They certainly do not. 100% test coverage would means that all branches of the code are being traversed at least once, as evidenced by coverage tools. This is generally unnecessary unless you are writing high-.assurance code  (formal methods may be more appropriate then). A unit means to test verify the correct functioning of a unit so that, upon bug fixing and refactoring one can easily check that functioning is still correct. If 100% coverage were intended, one would have to rewrite the unit tests, too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in one of the comment, the **core** aspect of BDD is to give you tests (that could be automated) that guarantee that your product is doing exactly that what it is supposed to do. And obviously: "not less than that".

And in that sense, BDD **plus** coverage helps you with making sure that your product is not doing **much more** than that.

In other words: assuming that all your BDD test pass; and your coverage is 75% ... than that *could* mean: 25% of your code base are **not required** in order to provide the behavior specified within your BDD testcases. Meaning: you can have a closer look at those 25% of untouched lines to understand why they are not needed; to then determine if there is a chance to delete same parts of that unused source code.

As in: the **2nd best thing** you can do as software developer: delete code from your code base without reducing the functionality of your product.

( and for the record: the **best** thing that a SW developer can do: add a new feature to his product that attracts new customers - deleting code helps your quality in the long run, but customers pay your salary short, medium and long term )

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: I found more clarity when you discussed the 75% vs the 25%. Reason being is that I add `fatalError()`s in some `guard` statements to help me easily find holes in my logic. However, when running my tests, the `else` clauses of the `guard` statements aren't executed since things are functioning as expected. I was creating additional tests to make the `guard` statements fall through to the `else` clause, therefore getting coverage for the `else` clauses, not knowing if that was appropriate for achieving 100% coverage.